# Data from several temp tables to be consolidated in one temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table `#temp1` that basically has a dump from one particular table

```
 Create Table #temp
([CaseSeveranceID] [int] ,
[OldCaseNbr] nvarchar(12) ,
[OldCDI] [int] ,
[NewCaseNbr] nvarchar(12),
[NewCDI] [int],
)

 Insert into #temp
 Select * from CSS where .....
```

I have an other table `cst` which basically has the relationship of

```
   css.caseSeveranceID = cst.CaseSeveranceID
```

This table `cst` has a column `Processed`, which could either have a value 'yes' or 'no'. The objective is to find out for each `caseSeveranceID` in `#temp` the count of number of rows where `Processed = 'yes'` and the total count of rows for each `CaseSeveranceID` found.

Example: CaseSeveranceID in `#temp` table `1002,1005,1008`

In table `CST`, we could have

```
 CSTId = 101
 CaseSEveranceID = 1002
 Processed = 'Yes'

 CSTId = 102
 CaseSEveranceID = 1002
 Processed = 'Yes'

 CSTId = 103
 CaseSEveranceID = 1002
 Processed = 'No'
```

and likewise for other records. I need in the end have the #temp table to have a column name `ProcessCount` along with the existing columns that will have the value for the `CaseSeveraneID 1002` as `2/3` (nbr of yes/total number).

What would be a the best way to do this. If you need any clarification or more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but should be something like this:

```
SELECT a.CSTId, sum(CASE WHEN Processed = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_yes, count(cst_id) as num_total
FROM #temp a
  INNER JOIN cst b ON a.caseSeveranceID = b.CaseSeveranceID
GROUP BY a.CSTId
```

Comment: Thx Jester. This gives me a base to continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CaseSeveranceID, 
  sum((case Processed when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)) as processed, 
  count(1) as totalCount
from cst
group by CaseSeveranceID
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your solution, specifically how it solves the problem and what the OP was getting wrong, it's nice to teach a little!